# Ansible when conditional with composed variable

Tags: ansible, conditional-statements, jinja2

I know ansible when-statements should not contain any jinja2 delimiters `{{}}`.
However, is there away to avoid this in the following situation:

```
vars:
  xvar: ['/path/file-blabla-abc', '/path/file-blabla-def']
  avar: blabla
  bvar: def

tasks:
- debug:
    msg: "yippie"
  when: "'/path/file-{{ avar }}-{{ bvar }}' in xvar"
```

Gives me the expected result:

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "yippie"
}
```

But also includes the warning:

```
[WARNING]: when statements should not include jinja2 templating delimiters
   such as {{ }} or {% %}. Found: '/path/file-{{ avar }}-{{ bvar }}'
```

How could I work around this problem? I cannot leave out the jinja2 delimiters here, as the variables would be undetectable by ansible then.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to create an additional variable

```
- debug:
    msg: OK
  vars:
    my_path: "/path/file-{{ avar }}-{{ bvar }}"
  when: my_path in xvar
```